# hyperlink download attr for a button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to write a function using jquery for a button

```
<input type="submit" id="submit></input>
```

when clicked this will be executed:

```
 <a download href="file.doc" ></a> 

<script>
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    //code here
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting `<input type="submit" id="submit" />` for `<input type="submit" id="submit></input>` . Initial `html` missing `"` after "submit" , `input` element is self-closing , does not require closing `</input>` ; call `event.preventDefault()` within `click` handler to prevent a parent `form` element from submitting , call `.click()` on `DOM` element `a`

```js
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    //code here
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector("a[download]").click()
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
<a download href="data,123"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a different way

```
<a href="uploads/file.pdf"></a>

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = $('a').attr('href');
});
```

Or without the anchor

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = "uploads/file.pdf";
});
```